# Difference between airflow container images with - build tag

Tags: airflow, dockerhub

Official Airflow git hub contains two kinds of image with same tag, I mean same airflow version and python versions, but one is having a postfix -build to tag name, and there is also difference in compressed image size

for example we would be having tags :

> docker pull apache/airflow:v1-10-stable-python3.8-build

> docker pull apache/airflow:v1-10-stable-python3.8

Why we have two images? And where they can be used

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I have the same question, thus, after heavy googling I find this
really interesting talk about internals of airflow containers images: https://youtu.be/wDr3Y7q2XoI?t=1664

This link guide you exactly to the moment, where speaker (who is Jarek Potiuk, the guy who contributes to airflow really a lot, credits to him. Actually I encourage you to watch the whole video) explains what is inside that *"build tagged"* images.

As I understand, *"build tagged"* image is used to build the smaller one. So you can use it if you want to gain more control during airflow setup process.
By the way, [here is a slides from that talk](https://airflowsummit.org/slides/h2-ProductionContainerImages.pdf).

I decided to use a smaller one in my humble deployment, and it works as it should)